# C# - Command sequence for Powershell or command prompt

Tags: c#, powershell, axis, prompt

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to create code in the C# console app that reboots a camera axis.
This can be done through the command-line FTP tool, Windows Command Prompt, or Powershell.

From the following command lines:

Command to connect the camera via FTP:
ftp 192.168.0.90

User:
root

Password:
pass

Reboot command:
quote site reboot

Finish:
bye

I tried as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

ftp namespace
{
    class program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process.Start("powershell.exe", "/C " + "ftp 192.168.0.90");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3 * 1000);
            Console.Write("root");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1 * 1000);
            Console.Write("pass");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1 * 1000);
            Console.Write("quote site reboot");
            

        }
    }
}
```

But I know it's wrong, I can't enter the username and password or the command for the reboot.
Can someone help me please ?
Thanks.

Comment: Use ftp client: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest?view=net-5.0

Comment: You could use a .Net class, either the built-in one linked above or one like WinSCP. However, I guess I don't understand why you wouldn't just use a batch file that calls `ftp.exe` with the `-s` option and a script file. You can see more about the client [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp). Is your purpose to make something that will sent this command, or is it your purpose to accomplish it *in C#*?